# How to connect Log Analytics to Office 365 after the OMS portal is over

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

Previously I used OMS portal to connect Office 365 to Log Analytics.
However, I do not know how to connect after OMS portal is discontinued.

Is there a way to connect Log Analytics to Office 365?

Comment: take a look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/solution-office-365)

Comment: Thanks to you I succeeded.

Comment: Do you mind if I post it, and can you help mark it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, please post.

Comment: Posted. Thanks :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/solution-office-365) about how to connect Log Analytics to Office 365.